# Cambiar estilos de un elemento creado en el DOM - Blazor

Tags: javascript, dom, blazor

tengo un problema, estoy creando desde cero un editor de texto(tipo word)  en el que debo de poder cambiar a negritas, italica, color, tipografia etc a el texto que el usuario va escribiendo, ya sea cuando este seleccione una parte del texto o a todo el contenido.

El problema es que estoy usando Blazor y hasta donde entiendo no es posible modificar directamente el DOM, por lo que el texto seleccionado lo estoy trayendo con el JS Interop y lo almaceno en una variable dentro de mi clase del componente, pero para poder cambiar el estilo al momento de seleccionar el texto en Javascript lo encierro en una etiqueta , para poder agregarle las clases de css estoy intentando llamar una funcion de javascript al hacer clic en un boton agregarle el estilo, pero no hace nada la funcion no entra al hacer clic.

> Javascript...

```
  window.selections = {
    getSelectedText: function () {
        var textSelected = window.getSelection();
        if (textSelected.rangeCount != null) {
            // Creates a new element, and insert the selected text with the chosen font inside
            var selection = document.createElement("span");
            selection.innerHTML = textSelected.toString();            
            var range = textSelected.getRangeAt(0);        
            range.deleteContents(); // Deletes the original selected text
            range.insertNode(selection); //and inserts the new element with the changed font
        } 
    },
    bold: function () {
        selection.style = "font-weight:" + "bold;";       
    },
    italic: function () {
        selection.style = "font-style:" + "italic;";
    },
    underlined: function () {
        selection.style = "text-decoration:" + "underlined;";
    }
}
```

> En mi clase del componente...

```
 async Task GetSelectedText()
    {
       SelectedText = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("selections.getSelectedText");
    }

 async Task SetBold()
    {           
   string bolds = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("selections.bold");
   
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    async Task setUnderlined()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("selections.underlined");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    async Task setItalics()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("selections.italic");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

> Razor

```
    <div class="toolBox">
    <Button OnClick="SetBold" Title="B"></Button>    
    <Button OnClick="setUnderlined" Title="U"></Button>       
    <Button OnClick="setItalics" Title="I"></Button>
    <input type="color" @bind="@fontColor" @bind:event="onchange"/>
</div>  
The text is @SelectedText
<div id="textBox" @onmouseup="GetSelectedText" contenteditable="true">   
</div>
```

> > > > CSS

```
  #textBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}

.underlined{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar guiandome sobre que esty haciendo mal.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pues no estoy muy seguro, pero revisa la consola del navegador a ver si tienes algún error, dado que en este código no tienes acceso a selection `bold: function () {
        selection.style = "font-weight:" + "bold;";       
    },`. deberías declararla en un ámbito global para que tengas acceso a esta variable.